# Capture substring within a string - dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I have a string:

```
ostring = "Ref('r1_featuring', ObjectId('5f475')"
```

What I am trying to do is search the string and check if it starts with `Ref`, if it does it should remove everything in the string and keep the substring `5f475`.

I know this can be done using a simple replace like so:

```
string = ostring.replace("Ref('r1_featuring', ObjectId('", '').replace("')", '')
```

But I cannot do it this way as it needs to all be **dynamic** as there are going to be different strings each time. So I need to do it in a way that it will search the string and check if it starts with `Ref`, if it does then grab the alphanumeric value.

**Desired Output:**

```
5f475
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that?

```py
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r"Ref.*'(.*)'\)$"

>>> m = re.match(pattern, "Ref('r1_featuring', ObjectId('5f475')")
>>> if m:
...     print(m.group(1))
...
5f475

# >= python3.8
>>> if m := re.match(pattern, "Ref('r1_featuring', ObjectId('5f475')"):
...     print(m.group(1))
...
5f475
```

Comment: I have included a desired output, it should just return the alphanumeric value within the quotes

Comment: first one worked for me, just had to substitute the string `"Ref('r1_featuring', ObjectId('5f475')"` to the variable `ostring` to make it dynamic

Answer (score 1):

a regex-free solution :)

```py
ostring = "Ref('r1_featuring', ObjectId('5f475')"

if ostring.startswith("Ref"):
    desired_part = ostring.rpartition("('")[-1].rpartition("')")[0]
```

[`str.rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition)